# What is causing my imported object to mutate in React Functional Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning about react and I have come across a scenario in which the behaviour is not what I expected.

I have a react funcional component like so:

```js
import { Box, Button, Grid, ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material';
import './styling/App.css';
import RawPayloadUI from './components/RawPayloadUI';
import FormUI from './components/FormUI';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Template } from './TemplateExporter';

function App() {

  const testFormFields = {...Template};
  const [currentUI, setCurrentUI] = useState('rawPayloadUI');
  const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState(testFormFields);

  const userInterfaces = ['rawPayloadUI', 'formUI'];

  const uiButtonHandler = e => {
    setFormFields(Template);
    //console.log(formFields);
    setCurrentUI(e.currentTarget.value)
  }

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div className="App">
        <div className='App-header'></div>
        <Grid id='Form' container sx={{ flexDirection: 'row', height: 'fit-content', marginTop: '1vh', justifyContent: 'center' }} spacing={2}>
            {userInterfaces.map((userInterface, idx) => {
              return (
                <Grid item key={idx}>
                  <Button value={userInterface} onClick={uiButtonHandler}>{userInterface}</Button>
                </Grid>
              )
            })}
          </Grid>
        {currentUI === 'formUI' && <FormUI onChange={setFormFields} formFields={formFields} />}
        {currentUI === 'rawPayloadUI' && <RawPayloadUI />}
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am trying to reset the `formFields` state back to the default value when the user switches to a different interface via the `uiButtonHandler()` method. But it seems like the values set by the `onChange` method of the `FormUI` component are being persisted which indicates to me that the underlying base object (`Template`) is being mutated.

Im not sure what part of the code is causing this mutation.

Can anyone explain which part of the code is causing the data from the `onChange` method to interact with the `Template`.

Comment: Spread syntax creates a [shallow copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Shallow_copy), if any of the properties of `Template` are nested objects then they will be prone to mutation. see: [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript). (TLDR: `const testFormFields = structuredClone(Template);`)

Comment: I think that half answers it.
I am unsure what is causing `testFormFields` to change thus affecting the properties of `Template`. I am only using it to set the default state of `formFields`

Comment: your `uiButtonHandler` is directly setting the state to `Template` which will directly mutate all of the imported object. Did you mean `setFormFields(structuredClone(Template));`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would like to clarify. And I apologise If I am missing something.

`Template` is being mutated.  The values set by the `onChange` method of the `FormUI` component are present in the 'mutated' `Template`. But how is that happening?

Comment: @Diagz he's already explained it 2-3 times, and provided links. It's not clear how much more clear we can be here. Try the other dupe link I added.

Comment: The clarity I was lacking from the answer which I now realize was that when I do `setFormFields(Template)` it is updating `formFields` state to be a reference to the `Template` object, and from that point onwards any changes made to formFields will mutate the base Template. This manifests in the values from the `onChange` method interacting with the `formFields` thus mutating the `Template`

Thankyou for your answers.